# Three js define axis of the geomatry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a box geometry,

I want to define where is the front of my geometry, setting a box:

```
var materialArray = [];
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'test/Three.js/images/xpos.png' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'test/Three.js/images/xneg.png' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'test/Three.js/images/ypos.png' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'test/Three.js/images/yneg.png' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'test/Three.js/images/zpos.png' ) }));
    materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'test/Three.js/images/zneg.png' ) }));
    var MovingCubeMat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);
    var MovingCubeGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100*meter, 50*meter, 300*meter, 1, 1, 1, materialArray );
    myMesh = new THREE.Mesh( MovingCubeGeom, MovingCubeMat );       
    scene.add( myMesh );
```

When i use `myMesh.lookAt(myTarget)` for aiming a target, side with texture "zneg.png" (which should be a front of object) is on the back side, object is oriented by "zpos.png" side facing to the target.

How can i define front and bottom, or top and back side of my object, for simple using rotations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object is in its default orientation, it is considered to be looking in the direction of its internal, positive z-axis. (The exception is the camera, which is looking in the direction of its internal negative z-axis.)

When you call `object.lookAt( target )`, the the object is rotated so its internal z-axis points in the direction of the target.

If you want a different side of your geometry to face the internal positive z-axis, apply a transform to your geometry right after you create it.

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotation( 0, Math.PI, 0 ) );
```

EDIT: You can also use one of the built-in methods. For example,

```
geometry.rotateY( Math.PI );
```

three.js r.100