# Three.js lookAt: how make mesh's positive x-axis point at the target?

Tags: matrix, three.js, geometry

This three.js issue https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14930 says:

> lookAt() orients the object so its local, positive z-axis points in the direction of the target, and its local x-axis is orthogonal to the world-space up direction. (For example, if the object were an airplane, its wings would remain level.)

I need the positive x-axis to point at the target, with the up vector points in the positive z-axis.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728293/three-js-define-axis-of-the-geomatry/25731386#25731386

Comment: But geometry.rotateY( Math.PI ); will rotate the geometry itself, which I *don't* want to do, it will interfere with the rest of the geometry of the model. Instead, I want to have lookAt() to take an axis, or possibly have .up determine the axis.

Comment: Here's a demo of orientation. I don't use lookUp, instead I create my own rotation which is OK.  https://agentscript.org/tests/threeYPR.html

Comment: I think you would find https://stackoverflow.com/a/17518092/1461008 useful in your case, at least for learning. Setting `rotation.order = 'ZYX'` should give you heading, pitch, and roll behavior in your coordinate system: `mesh.rotation.set( 0, pitch, heading )`; That is just one way to address your issue.